# No module named _mysql when running the executable built using pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, pyinstaller

I have build a python script which uses `MySQLDB`. I am able to run the code locally and everything works fine but when after building the executable using `pyinstaller` and running it, I am getting this error `No module named _mysql Line 19 in path MySQLDb/__init.py`

Please help.

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/323

Comment: If you explicitly `import _mysql` and `import _mysql_exceptions` -- either directly or via a hook -- that'll resolve it.

Comment: Also closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436132/pyinstaller-spec-file-importerror-no-module-named-blah

Comment: While building I see this : hidden import _mysql not found

Comment: I have tried all possible solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: How to import module via a hook?

Comment: So it *is* looking for it at build time? Then you need to find out why it's not finding it. Too many possibilities to be able to speculate here -- maybe the C library was built for a different interpreter, for example; the Python bits will port straight across, the C parts not so much. Make sure it's the same Python install (same virtualenv, etc) with pyinstaller that you're also successfully testing with at dev time.